# Error Broken pipe while install chrubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, fdisk, chromebook

Okay, I need help
My chromebook is Acer c720
So., I trying to follow this guide -> http://www.amirkurtovic.com/blog/installing-chrubuntu-on-the-samsung-arm-chromebook-a-step-by-step-photo-guide/
I go to dev mode, to dev console, insert my sd card(16gb)..
check my fdisk (sudo fdisk -l) there I have:
/dev/sda ...
/dev/ ... bla bla
and /dev/sdb what I guess is sdcard(then I plugged off, this is vanished)
so then I trying write(acer c720 is x86 rigth?):
wget http://goo.gl/tnyga; sudo bash tnyga /dev/sdb1 and I have error Cannot write to '-' (Broken pipe),
so I read about it and people say it's because sdcard have to be ext4, so I trying found out how I can do it, and try typed:
sudo fdisk /dev/sdb
-o
-n
-p
-1
-8192
-default
-w
"partition table has been altered!"
okay, then I have -> /dev/sdb1 bla bla system: Linux
okay, guess I have to format this into ext4
typed: sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
done done done.
okay, check again fdisk -l, but there still system linux.. not get it..
okay, check by another way, typed: sudo blkid
bla bla.. /deb/sdb1 TYPE='ext4'..
hmm think mb it's okay and trying again, but there was same error with Cannot write '-'...
I read about something fstab.. what I have to write there about /dev/sdb.. but I don't get it how I can do it.. gedit not supported here, I trying sudo vi.. but there he say me file is read only...
Okay.. any help, please)﻿

Comment: Could you please clarify exactly what you are having issues with, specifically?

Comment: I have issue with this error "Cannot write '-' (Broken pipe)", I don't understand why she fire and how fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install chrubuntu from another respo from this guide and that's works: http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.ru/2013/10/chrubuntu-for-new-chromebooks-now-with.html